# Android jetpack component - toast on navigation drawer click

Tags: android, android-jetpack

I am using navigation jetpack and have set up navigation drawer. Every thing works fine. But the problem is I want to show a toast when user clicks "nav_share" but it is not showing...
[image: my nav drawer..i want to show toast when user clicks order history whose id is "nav_share"]

here is how i made navigation drawer

```
DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.navigation_home, R.id.navigation_dashboard, R.id.navigation_plan, R.id.navigation_notifications)
                .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
                .build();

        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);
```

my menu for navigation drawer is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:showIn="navigation_view">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_home"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
            android:title="@string/menu_home" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_gallery"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
            android:title="@string/menu_gallery" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_slideshow"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_slideshow"
            android:title="@string/menu_slideshow" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_tools"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_manage"
            android:title="@string/menu_tools" />
    </group>

    <item android:title="Communicate">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_share"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_share"
                android:title="@string/menu_share" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_send"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_send"
                android:title="@string/menu_send" />
        </menu>
    </item>

</menu>
```

finally:

```
@Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {

        int id = menuItem.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_share)
            Toast.makeText(LauncherActivity.this, "Click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
```

i want that click toast...i cannot see what am i missing....

Comment: try debugging it

Comment: i tired but when i did that...my onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) function is never executed although i have done navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this); ..

Comment: The `NavigationUI.setupWithNavController()` call is calling `setNavigationItemSelectedListener()` itself internally, which overrides the call you made earlier. Your `onNavigationItemSelected()` is not going to be called, since the Navigation framework is handling the `NavigationView` clicks.

Comment: @MikeM. if I add  navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this); on last of my onCreate() then the toast is shown...but now i cannot navigate to my dashboard, plans or profile .... how can i show the toast and be able to navigate between my fragments..can you elaborate??

Comment: Right, because then your call is overriding the one that `NavigationUI.setupWithNavController()` sets. Why do you want to show a `Toast` there? Surely that's not what you ultimately want to do, yeah?

Comment: yeah,i will be adding logout option there..where i need to add a alert dialog to confirm logout...so i am testing with toast so later i can implement a alert dialog

Comment: Well, it'd probably be less work, in the end, to just go ahead and set up a stub dialog destination. Otherwise, I _think_ you can set your `OnNavigationItemSelectedListener`, and call [`NavigationUI.onNavDestinationSelected()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/ui/NavigationUI.html#onNavDestinationSelected(android.view.MenuItem,%20androidx.navigation.NavController)) in `onNavigationItemSelected()`, if `id != R.id.nav_share`. I'm not very familiar with the Navigation framework, yet, but that seems to be the way to do it, AFAICT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if any one wants the answer..i did some research and finally found a solution to it...hope it helps....

```
NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
MenuItem shareItem = navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.nav_share);
shareItem.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
     @Override
     public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {

     Toast.makeText(LauncherActivity.this, "click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     //do as you want with the button click

      DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
      drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

      return true;
     }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
 NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
 navigationView.bringToFront()
 navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had your problem and came up with the solution

```
NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_home);
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);

    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
            int id = menuItem.getItemId();
            if (id == R.id.nav_share) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "nav_share", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            NavigationUI.onNavDestinationSelected(menuItem, navController);
            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

In case if anyone is still searching for the answer as to how we can tie up navigation destinations and also handle click on menu items of the navigation drawer, it has been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57846680/3283350

Answer (score 0):

**Android Jetpack Navigation - Custom Action with Drawer Item**

> Simple step and easy

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(),NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener{

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    val navView: NavigationView = binding.navView
    navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main)
    navView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this)

 }

 override fun onNavigationItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {

    val url: String? = when (item.itemId) {
        R.id.nav_privacy_policy -> MenuItemUrl.PRIVACY_POLICY
        R.id.nav_term_condition -> MenuItemUrl.TERM_AND_CONDITION
        R.id.nav_contact_us -> MenuItemUrl.CONTACT_US
        R.id.nav_feedback -> MenuItemUrl.FEEDBACK
        R.id.nav_help_support -> MenuItemUrl.HELP_AND_SUPPORT
        R.id.nav_faq -> MenuItemUrl.FAQ
        R.id.nav_about_us -> MenuItemUrl.ABOUT_US
        else -> null
    }

    if (url != null) Methods.openBrowser(this@MainActivity, url) // Do anything here ex. show toast etc.
    NavigationUI.onNavDestinationSelected(item, navController)
    drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
    return true
 }

}
```